# Authentication : app_dev.php/_wdt/511509b611682 instead of homepage

Tags: symfony

I'm looking at security in Symfony 2.0 and I have a problem I can't explain.

My security bundle is very simple for now.

I try to put everything working before putting real providers.

So, now, when I go on the site, It sends me on the login form as expected. I put the user and the password and then, instead of home page, i am send to "/.../app_dev.php/_wdt/511509b611682" (different number each time).

My user isn't marked as authenticated in the debug toolbar.

If i take off the end of the url, i arrive on homepage. My user seems to be identified and authenticated in the debug toolbar.

This arrives only in dev environment. In prod environment, it seems to work as expected.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "when I go on the site" does it mean a deeplink?  or just the root path?  Any browsercache on relaoding the page?  How do you decide to forward to which page after login?  How does your "simple" bundle handles the login?

Comment: "when I go on the site" means typing the root url. Borwsercache and Symfony cache are cleaned. I would like to go on the page i typed first... My bundle is a light implementation of the custom userProvider and authenticationProvider shown in the cookbook (no service is called yet. It is hardcoded for tests). Thanks.

Comment: This sounds for my that either the routing in dev mode is overwriting something( maybe a copy'n'paste error) or your token handling has some problems

Comment: Maybe... I don't think so but... If the answer given by artworkad doesn't work, i'll look deeper in this direction.

Answer (score 15):

Further to @artworkad's answer, you have to add the `dev` firewall *before* your main firewall, otherwise it will never match:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            #...
```

Answer (score 4):

When you log in using development environment you will be redirected to `index_dev.php/_wdt/4e95412bc6871`.

WDT aka web debug toolbar can be removed from the scope of the firewall via

```
dev:
  pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
  security: false
```

Actually it is not related to SecurityBundle, anyways it is documented here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/368

Answer (score 2):

Also you can put this lines in access_control:

```
{ path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
{ path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

but I prefer keep my access_control for only my app routes.