# Symfony2 (v2.3.4) - Acces denied when using FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

When i go to project/web/ the application redirect me to te web/login where is a form for logging in.

But when i got authorized, after submit the form i got back to project/web/ path with Acces denied exception. What is wrong with my settings, i can't figure it out.

routing.yml

```
my_backend:
    resource: "@MyBackendBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path:                     /login
            use_forward:                    false
            check_path:                     /login_check
            post_only:                      true
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path:            /
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path
            use_referer:                    false
            failure_path:                   null
            failure_forward:                false
            username_parameter:             _username
            password_parameter:             _password
            csrf_parameter:                 _csrf_token
            intention:                      authenticate
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you authenticate you are being set another role then ROLE_ADMIN. Please use the app_dev.php version of the site and at bottom it will tell you your role after you access the access denied page.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ROLE_ADMIN` associated to your user?

Also, have you tried removing `anonymous` config parameter or at least setting it to default ("~")? If I understand correctly, your entire app requires authentication but `/login` gives means of entering user credentials. Is that correct?

Comment: ROLE_ADMIN is associated with my user (i promoted him with the --super parameter)

I must try to remove anonymous parameter and see does it help 

Yes you understand correctly. All app should be only for authenticated users (admins), only /login path is for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for answers. I resolved the problem.

After i created and promoted user with `promote --super command` he obtain `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` role. But in access control of my app there was only `path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN`

so i modified it to be `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` and now it works without Access Denied exception.

But i have one more question in this case. Now when i use app.php version everything goes ok (after login at `/login` page i'm redirected to `/`) but with app_dev.php version, after login i'm redirected to `web/_wdt/TOKEN` with empty page.

Comment: add this dev firewall before your main firewall: dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811980/authentication-app-dev-php-wdt-511509b611682-instead-of-homepage

Answer (score 0):

set up a role hierarchy, so that a super admin can access all routes defined as admin-accessible:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

[Symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)