# Redirect after the login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I used FOSUserBundle and i changed the basic template to my own. When i set rules in my securite file like below

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

then everything is ok but when i change it like below

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

my site after login redirects me to "web/app_dev.php/_wdt/7e8a2e" and i don't know why.

What is it "_wdt/7e8a2e " ?

Comment: Here you should find your answer:

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811980/authentication-app-dev-php-wdt-511509b611682-instead-of-homepage**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a new access_control rule to allow anonymous access to this:

- { path: ^/_(profiler|wdt)/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

you could also add a new firewall rule to avoid security in this url